# $Site.Domain is not working in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vf-email-template

Trying to read the force.com subdomain URL host-name in Visualforce Email template as below.

```
 <td style="text-align: center;font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;font-weight:300; padding: 20px;"> <span style="background-color:#2ea5f3; border: 3px solid #2ea5f3; color: #ffffff !important;font-size: 17px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 190px;border-radius: 200px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" href="{!$Site.Domain}/seed?seedkey={!relatedTo.Key__c}" target="_blank">keyLink</a> </span>
```

`$Site.Domain` in Email site domain is empty as `/seed?seedkey=23132112`

Answer (score 0):

The [$Site global type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_site.htm) is only meaningful in the context of a Salesforce Site.

If you want to include a link/url reference within a Visualforce email template you could either **use a Custom Metadata Type or a Custom Setting** where you would store such value.